# How to stop YouTube iframe embed from autoplaying

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, autoplay

I've made no code changes, but in the last few hours, all my embedded youtube videos (using the new iframe html5 method) started autoplaying.

From searching around online, I found some that recommended putting `?autoplay=0` in the src URL, but that doesn't work.

Another suggestion said I'd have to go back to the old method, and that that's the only one that allows us to turn off autoplay.

I'd really rather not do that, but certainly will if I need to, but the bigger question is,

**Q1:** Is there another way to stop it from autoplaying other than reverting to the old embed?

**Side question:** What changed in the past few hours that made all my videos start autoplaying?

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/N2tlvo5CI4Y?autoplay=0"
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hear it's the GoogleCast extension.
Disable it
Close Chrome
Run Chrome
Should be fixed for now.

Comment: Any reference to this being the case?

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me. It's incredibly annoying too.